# Use Mongoose Stream via Reactive Extensions for JavaScript

Tags: node.js, mongoose, rxjs

I've been convinced to use Reactive Extensions for JavaScript, so I'm trying to use it with Mongoose like this:

```
var subscription = Rx.Node.fromStream(Meeting.find().stream())
.subscribe(function () {
  console.log(arguments);
});
subscription.dispose();
```

But nothing happens.
What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
Rx.Node.fromStream(Meeting.find().stream()).subscribe(function (data) {
  console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
});
```